# Can a PySimpleGUI InputOptionMenu be updated?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I want to update values of a PySimpleGUI **Input Option Menu**. The following initially assigns contents of the 'names' list to the **Listbox**. This is overwritten when the 'new_values' list is assigned. So, there's no problem updating a **Listbox**, but the **InputOptionMenu** element is not updating.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

names = ['Roberta', 'Kylie']

layout = [[sg.Listbox(names, size=(20, 4), key='_LIST_')],
          [sg.InputOptionMenu(names, size=(20, 4), key='_LIST_')]]

window = sg.Window('').Layout(layout).Finalize()

new_values = ['Bill', 'Jeff']
window.Element('_LIST_').Update(new_values)

while True:
    event, values = window.Read()
    if event is None or event == 'Exit':
        break

window.Close()
```

My expectation is both elements would be updated to Bill and Jeff. The **Listbox** is, but the **InputOptionMenu** shows Roberta and Kylie.

Answer (score 4):

You can indeed update to new values.  You've got a parameter in the update call out of order.  The first parameter, `value` sets the currently shown value.  The **second** parameter, `values` is the one you need.

The fix is to add the parameter name to your call:

```
window.Element('_LIST_').Update(values=new_values)
```

Additionally, you must not name 2 keys the same.  They have to be unique among the layout.  I would call the other one `_OPTIONS_` or something along those lines.

There was a bug in the Update code for Option Menu that has now been fixed and checked into GitHub.  The fix was uploaded to PyPI as version 3.27.

Here is your code reworked and tested with the latest PySimpleGUI code.  I've included an extra parameter to the OptionMenu.Update call to show you how to explicitly set a

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

names = ['Roberta', 'Kylie']

layout = [[sg.Listbox(names, size=(20, 4), key='_LIST_')],
          [sg.OptionMenu(names, size=(20, 4), key='_OPT_')]]

window = sg.Window('').Layout(layout).Finalize()

new_values = ['Bill', 'Jeff']
window.Element('_LIST_').Update(values=new_values)
window.Element('_OPT_').Update(values=new_values, value='Jeff')

while True:
    event, values = window.Read()
    if event is None or event == 'Exit':
        break

window.Close()
```

Comment: It works if you get the latest code from GitHub as described in the answer.

Comment: When running with latest release https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/13696193/54960548-72d50400-4f33-11e9-9fb9-a0d88c7deac4.gif

Comment: Still not understanding the downvoting when the OP indicates that the code works. Really scrambled to get this problem solved too.

Comment: I upvoted your answer to get rid of the negative score. =)